# PHP -- jquery ajax syntax help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to using jquery and i have written the following code and it does not work and i am not able to figure out what the mistake is ..syntax might also be wrong.

It has 2 submit buttons while using button1 it should get info from the DB and display on the same page.i.e., get the title from the DB and display on the same page.

While second submit button is used to submit title into the DB and update it(written in script_2.php).

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
id: <input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit to script 1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Submit to script 2" />
title:<input type="text" name="title"/>
</form>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

$("#button1").click(function(){
$.post('script_1.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output) {
    $('#age').html(output).show();

}) ;
}) ;



$("#button2").click(function(){
$('form#myForm').attr({action: "script_2.php"});
$('form#myForm').submit();
});
});

</script>
</head>
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `});` to close the `$("#button1").click` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $.post('script_1.php', { name: form.name.value },function(output) {$('#age').html(output).show();});
        });
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $('form#myForm').attr({action: "script_2.php"});
            $('form#myForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many closing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: it was a typo ..it is not present in the actual code ..ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `attr()` expects strings, not an object, like:

```
$('form#myForm').attr("action", "script_2.php");
```

You form is before your `<head>` tag. It should be after your `</head>` and in a `<body>` tag.

You are putting the results of your ajax call in an element with id `age`, but I don't see any element with that id on your page.

That's all for errors (that I see as of now), but you can also speed up your selecter here `$('form#myForm')` by changing it to `$('#myForm')` since id's are unique, and I doubt you have any element with the id myForm which isn't a form.